# get the highest GPA scored by male and female students from each school

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have tables

```
TBL_STD_MARKS 
SCHOOL_ID   SYMBOL_NO       AVG_GPA
1               211             3.8
1               255             3.5
1               212             2.90
2               311             3.85
2               312             3.75
3               411             2.98
3               412             3.00


TBL_STD_INFO
SCHOOL_ID   SYMBOL_NO   STUDENT_NAME    GENDER
1               211         S1              M   
1               255         S2              F
1               212         S3              M
2               311         S22             M
2               312         S23             M   
3               411         S31             M
3               412         S32             F   


TBL_SCHOOL
SCHOOL_ID       SCHOOL_NAME
1               SCHOOL11
2               SCHOOL22
3               SCHOOL33
```

I am trying to write a query to get the highest `AVG_GPA` scored by male and female students from each schools. But my query is giving all the rows of the table.

```
 WITH cte
    AS (
        SELECT D.SCHOOL_NAME
            ,A.SYMBOL_NO
            ,B.STUDENT_NAME         
            ,B.GENDER
            ,A.AVG_GPA
        FROM TBL_STD_MARKS A
        INNER JOIN TBL_STD_INFO B ON A.SYMBOL_NO = B.SYMBOL_NO
        INNER JOIN TBL_SCHOOL D ON A.SCHOOL_ID = D.SCHOOL_ID
        )
    SELECT SCHOOL_NAME
            ,SYMBOL_NO
            ,STUDENT_NAME       
        ,MAX(DISTINCT CASE 
                WHEN GENDER = 'M'
                    THEN AVG_GPA
                END) AS MALE_GPA
        ,MAX(DISTINCT CASE 
                WHEN GENDER = 'F'
                    THEN AVG_GPA
                END) AS FEMALE_GPA
    FROM CTE
    GROUP BY SCHOOL_NAME,SYMBOL_NO
            ,STUDENT_NAME
```

Answer (score 2):

use `row_number()` window function

```
     with cte as (  
          SELECT D.SCHOOL_NAME
        ,A.SYMBOL_NO
        ,B.STUDENT_NAME         
        ,B.GENDER
        ,A.AVG_GPA,row_number()over(partition by D.SCHOOL_NAME, B.GENDER order by A.AVG_GPA desc) rn
    FROM TBL_STD_MARKS A
    INNER JOIN TBL_STD_INFO B ON A.SYMBOL_NO = B.SYMBOL_NO
    INNER JOIN TBL_SCHOOL D ON A.SCHOOL_ID = D.SCHOOL_ID
    ) select * from cte where rn=1
```

Comment: What if I want to order by AVG_GPA, I mean the Male or Female student with highest GPA should be in top and then the corresponding Male or Female student of the same school. I tried by joining `select * from cte where rn=1 order by AVG_GPA desc` but it's doing order by AVG_GPA only. Please help!!!

Comment: @nischalinn i am not understand what you asked , can you please ask a new question with proper data example because i think my answer is already solved your current problem

Comment: this query is showing result as order by school_name. but what if I want to show the school with highest GPA on top.

Comment: use order by AVG_GPA desc

Answer (score 0):

```
select D.SCHOOL_NAME
        ,A.SYMBOL_NO
        ,B.STUDENT_NAME         
        ,B.GENDER
        ,A.AVG_GPA
    FROM TBL_STD_MARKS A
    INNER JOIN TBL_STD_INFO B ON A.SYMBOL_NO = B.SYMBOL_NO
    INNER JOIN TBL_SCHOOL D ON A.SCHOOL_ID = D.SCHOOL_ID
where B.GENDER='M' OR B.GENDER='F' and A.AVG_GPA=(select max(AVG_GPA) from TBL_STD_MARKS)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT tbs.SCHOOL_ID,
CASE WHEN GENDER = 'F' THEN
      MAX(AVG_GPA) END AS HighestFemaleGPA,
CASE WHEN GENDER = 'M' THEN
      MAX(AVG_GPA) END AS HighestMaleGPA
FROM @TBL_STD_MARKS stdM
INNER JOIN @TBL_SCHOOL tbs
ON  tbs.SCHOOL_ID = stdM.SCHOOL_ID
INNER JOIN @TBL_STD_INFO stdI
ON stdI.SYMBOL_NO = stdM.SYMBOL_NO
GROUP BY tbs.SCHOOL_ID,GENDER
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT std_marks.SCHOOL_ID,school.SCHOOL_NAME, std_info.GENDER, MAX(std_marks.AVG_GPA) 
as MAX_AVG_GPA
FROM TBL_STD_MARKS std_marks
INNER JOIN TBL_STD_INFO std_info ON std_info.SYMBOL_NO = std_marks.SYMBOL_NO
INNER JOIN TBL_SCHOOL school ON school.SCHOOL_ID = std_marks.SCHOOL_ID
GROUP BY std_info.GENDER, std_marks.SCHOOL_ID, school.SCHOOL_NAME
ORDER BY std_marks.SCHOOL_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

select ts.School_Id, ts.School_Name, tsi.Gender, max(tsm.Avg_GPA) as Avg_GPA from Tbl_School ts join
 Tbl_Std_Info tsi on ts.School_Id = tsi.School_Id join Tbl_Std_Marks tsm
 on tsi.Symbol_No = tsm.Symbol_No group by ts.School_Id ,ts.School_Name, tsi.Gender

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assume this is our table. The query below will help you:

```
Select a.SchoolId, a.Gender,
  (Select max(GPA) From [Test].[guest].[School] where SchoolId = a.SchoolId and Gender = 
  a.Gender) as GPA
  from [Test].[guest].[School] a
  Group by SchoolId, Gender
```